# git svn branch results in Authentication failed

Tags: git-svn

I'm trying to do all of my branching and merging via `git-svn`, however I'm hung up on the branching in subversion.

Our admin tells me that I have full read/write permissions on the repo, and I CAN fetch the latest code.

For a test, I deleted my `~/.subversion/svn.simple` directory and ran this.

```
04:13 pm [214423L] C:\Dev\MyFooApp.Bar [master]
$ git svn fetch
Authentication realm: <https://code:443> VisualSVN Server
Password for 'cflorell': {my password}

04:14 pm [214423L] C:\Dev\MyFooApp.Bar [master]
$ git svn fetch

04:14 pm [214423L] C:\Dev\MyFooApp.Bar [master]
$
```

Also, if I clone the repo using Tortoise, and then create a branch using `svn` it appears to work.

```
04:43 pm [214423L] C:\Dev\MyFooApp.Bar
$ svn copy https://code/svn/MyFooApp.Bar/trunk https://code/svn/MyFooApp.Bar/branches/test-branch -m "test branch"
Committing transaction...
Committed revision 93.
```

But upon trying to create a branch using `git-svn`, it still says my auth is invalid.

```
04:14 pm [214423L] C:\Dev\MyFooApp.Bar [master]
$ git svn branch develop
Copying https://code/svn/MyFooApp.Bar/trunk at r92 to https://code/svn/MyFooApp.Bar/branches/develop...
Authentication failed: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'https://code/svn/MyFooApp.Bar/trunk': No more credentials or we tried too many times.
Authentication failed at C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64/libexec/git-core\git-svn line 1196.

04:14 pm [214423L] C:\Dev\MyFooApp.Bar [master]
$
```

My `config` file is *I believe* correct.

```
[core]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = false
    bare = false
    logallrefupdates = true
    symlinks = false
    ignorecase = true
    hideDotFiles = dotGitOnly
[svn-remote "svn"]
    url = https://code/svn/MyFooApp.Bar
    fetch = trunk:refs/remotes/svn/trunk
    branches = branches/*:refs/remotes/svn/*
    tags = tags/*:refs/remotes/svn/tags/*
```

Where might I be going wrong with all of this?

Comment: Did you ever solve this? I've run into something similar and had to  resort to using the svn client to create tag branches because I couldn't figure out a way past this.

Comment: I never did, and I convinced our Corp to move to GIT.

Comment: Well for your sake I'm glad for that outcome! Unfortunately the Wordpress plugin repository seems to require Subversion to deploy plugins, just passed `r1360603`, shows no sign of slowing, and I don't hold the clout to convince it to migrate to DVCS.

Comment: I've also hit this and have yet to figure out why, I'm able to push to the svn server, I'm able to pull from the server. Yet the Git SVN branch command gives me this same error each time as well.

Comment: I'm stuck in the exact same situation.  Spent the last hour trying to figure out how to tag a simple release on the WP plugin repo, still to no avail...

Comment: It's strange I have the same issue. Just nine 9 days ago I was able to create a tag on WP plugin repo, but today it's giving the same error as described above

Answer (score 6):

Note that more than a year later (March 2017), Git 2.13+ (Q2 2017) should avoid that `git svn` authentication issue.

See [commit e0688e9](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e0688e9b28f2c5ff711460ee8b62077be5df2360) (06 Mar 2017) by [Hiroshi Shirosaki (`shirosaki`)](https://github.com/shirosaki).

It recognizes that authentication fails with `svn branch` while `svn rebase` and `svn dcommit` work fine without authentication failures.

```
$ git svn branch v7_3
Copying https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx at r27519
to https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx/v7_3...
Can't create session: Unable to connect to a repository at URL
'https://xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx': No more
credentials or we tried too many times.
Authentication failed at
C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64/libexec/git-core\git-svn line 1200.
```

> We add auth configuration to `SVN::Client->new()` to fix the issue.

Comment: This bug still exists in Git 2.7.4 :-(

Comment: @StevenByks That is possible. 2.7 is older than 2.13. Is 2.7 the version usually found in Ubuntu 14.04? Can you upgrade Git?

Comment: I read 2.13 as 2.1.3, ops!  I'm on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS and sadly 2.7.4 is the distro version.  But I upgraded to 2.18 using the ppa, and it works now!

Answer (score 3):

So it looks like there is a conflict between Tortoise SVN and git-svn, I'm not sure if this exists in other versions of SVN or not but I uninstalled Tortoise SVN and was then able to branch using `git svn branch branchName`

```
C:\Files\Source\Repos\applications\core\App01>git svn branch branchName
Copying http://url/svn/company/applications/core/App01/trunk
 at r7071 to http://url/svn/company/applications/core/App01/
branches/branchName...
Found possible branch point: http://url/svn/company/applications/core/App01/trunk => http://url/svn/company/applications/core/App01/branches/branchName, 7071
Found branch parent: (refs/remotes/origin/branchName) f8ba2fd450c30d4812b7549217eae1b2d5c7dd00
Following parent with do_switch
Successfully followed parent
r15037 = 52dd759833fd89c7be03f89093aba38090b3288f (refs/remotes/origin/branchName)

C:\Files\Source\Repos\applications\core\App01>
```

Going to try some other SVN Browser for the time being and see if that also has an issue.

Comment: This is consistent with the fact that I too ran Tortoise SVN before attempting the switch to git-svn.

Comment: I'm on Linux and have never used anything but the git command line tools, Tortoise is not involved in this for me.

Comment: I previously had TortoiseGit installed, and this worked; I recently formatted my PC, reinstalled the same suite of utilities, and am now hitting this issue.  So although I have a Tortoise utility, it's not Tortoise SVN (and it definitely worked with it installed previously)...

Comment: My experince here  was this:
I had TortoiseSVN installed,
I then installed git for windows including git-bash,
using git-svn worked fine
I then updated TortoiseSVN and then git-svn started this behavior
Un-installing TortoiseSVN restored function to git-svn.

Answer (score 0):

According to https://gist.github.com/kasparsd/3749872/563011118e33900b3a0ca89ec37f3c99be8e9c49 , there's no way to authenticate using git svn tag (used to work, but stopped working).

Instead, use svn directly to submit a tag:

```
svn cp <trunk-ul> <tag-url> -m "creating tag x.x"
```

It will ask to store your password in plain text though.