# Unable to authenticate when creating upstream branch using git-svn

Tags: windows, cygwin, git-svn, git-bash, git-extensions

I am unable to use git-svn to create a branch on an svn server, using the `git svn branch <branchname>` command on windows using either git-bash, cygwin or git extensions.

I would like some guidance/suggestions on how to diagnose and debug this issue.

The output on git-bash and cygwin:

```
$ git svn branch upstream-branch-name
Copying https://***redacted*** at r132578 to https://***redacted***/branches/upstream-branch-name...
Can't create session: Unable to connect to a repository at URL 'https://***redacted***': No more credentials or we tried too many times.
Authentication failed at C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64/libexec/git-core\git-svn line 1199.
```

For information, I have cygwin, and TortoiseSVN installed as svn providers on my system.

EDIT1: Additionally, I am able to do `git svn rebase` and `git svn dcommit` without any error

Comment: Could you commit directly svn? preferably command line. You could try define your svn username to git-svn explicitly via --username

Comment: Yes, I am able to commit directly to svn, I have been using that as a temporary workaround

Answer (score 0):

Check first your Git version in your Cygwin environment.
I [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42797495/6309) a Git 2.13+ (March 2017) should be more robust when it comes to authentication issue.

For testing, try (as [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35710640/6309)) to uninstall TortoiseSVN and see if the `git svn branch` does work then.